# Cannot add a domain to existing drupal 7 site

Tags: 7, configuration, ssl

Sorry in advance if this is a dumb question, I can't seem to figure out how to add a domain name to a D7 site, (currently using an IP). The website is hosted on digitalocean, the new domain is from namescheap, and the site is Drupal v 7.41.

(The end goal is to apply a letsencrypt ssl certificate to the website, which is not possible without a domain name - so if anyone has better advice than bothering with the domain please let me know! SSL was implemented by following this step-by-step guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04)

The new domain has been added to digitaloceanl, and I've changed the `$base_url` variable in `settings.php` to the new domain. Trying to reach the site by the new domain returns the following Privacy Error warning:

"NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID"

And running tests on the ssl certificate return "MISMATCH,"

Both of which seem to imply the new domain is not working properly.

Not sure what other information to supply, so if anyone has a suggestion please let me know!

Thanks,

Jill

Comment: does your `$base_url` match what you entered in `sudo certbot --apache -d example.com` ?

Comment: It does, plus a protocol

Comment: does it also match the `ServerName` value in your apache configuration file(httpd.conf)? You may also wanna try asking in Serverfault stack exchange.

Comment: I've only been able to find that variable set in a file named " 000-default.conf" and no... it is in fact set to the production site's domain....

Edit: it's set to something completely different - when I go to that domain it forwards me to the IP address

Comment: try looking for vhosts.conf in the conf.d directory then.

Comment: I did a search for all the conf.d files, and they all seem to be empty. Is that possible?

Comment: yes, the conf.d is a directory where you put additional apache configurations that end in .conf. Did you skip this step?: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: I did not create the site, but maybe..? If you think this will solve the issue I will give it a shot, unless there's a risk (I don't want to break this website....)